# I'd rather you not told me

Tags: would-rather

1. Which sentence is the grammatically correct one? I find both on Google, and now I am at loss.

> a) I’d rather you did not tell me.
>
> b) I’d rather you not told me.

or

> c) I'd rather you hadn't told me???

2. I initially assumed that if the structure "I'd rather not have eaten that hamburger yesterday" is correct, then why shouldn’t there be "I’d rather you not told me"?

Comment: I found 412,000 results for "rather you did not tell ", and only 8 results for "rather you not told". This should tell you that "rather you not told" is bad English

Comment: (a) is correct if they haven't told you yet, (c) if they have but you wish they hadn't.

Comment: You can say 'I'd rather you not **tell** me' if they haven't told you yet, but might.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said: Unmarked infinitive ***tell*** works fine in this context (with implied auxiliary *I'd rather you **do / did** not do that*). It's essentially the same "elision of auxiliary verb" in OP's second example *I’d rather you **had** not told me*.

Comment: ... *I'd rather you **hadn't done** that* unambiguously expresses dissatisfaction about ***something done in the past***, whereas *I'd rather you **didn't do** that* expresses dissatisfaction with something you're either *currently doing* (at time of utterance), or *likely* to do unless you decide / are able to oblige the request.

Comment: FumbleFingers, thank you a lot for explanation.